# Change opacity during slideDown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity, slidedown

I have and  object with these css parameters:

```
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:25%;
 width:50%;
 height: 300px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 display:none;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #807980 0%,
        #3d323d);
 background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#807980),
        to(#3d323d));
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(46, 50, 50, 1);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px rgba(46, 50, 50, 1);
 -o-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px rgba(46, 50, 50, 1);
 box-shadow:         0px 0px 10px rgba(46, 50, 50, 1);
 opacity: 0.2;
```

And I have this javascript which I'm using to slide down and slide up this div:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#main_div').click(function(){
 $('#slide_down').slideToggle(2000);
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Before I made this slide down with css3, hover and transition and I was changing opacity of the object in css, but now when I'm using javascript instead to slide it down. Is there any chance to change object opacity from 0.2 to 0.8 during sliding down? So it create very nice effect? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to create a custom animation function using `animate` instead of `slideToggle`:

```
var sdh = $('#slide_down').css('height');

$('#main_div').click(function() {
    var $sd = $('#slide_down');
    if ($sd.css('display') == 'none') {
        $sd.css('height', 0);
        $sd.css('display', 'block');
        $sd.animate({ 
            height: sdh,
            opacity: 0.8
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        $sd.animate({
            height: 0,
            opacity: 0.2
        }, 1000, function(){
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        });
    }
});​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ffwva/)

Comment: This look exactly like what i was looking for. But for weird reason I can't make it work. :(

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I just copied variable wrong way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use .animate() at the same time to achieve that effect:

```
$('#slide_down').slideToggle(2000);
$('#slide_down').animate({ opacity: 0.8 }, 2000);
```

I'm testing it here, but it seems to perform first one and then the other: http://jsfiddle.net/yHCvL/

Comment: It did change opacity. But what I was trying to achieve. Is till it's sliding down change opacity from 0.2 to 0.8 and when it's sliding back up, other way around, from 0.8 to 0.2.

Comment: I thought jQuery would perform both at the same time, but it does one first then the other. So it would be probably better to do as @mVChr suggests in his answer, creating a new animation.